# My laptop is itself generating w64.exe files. Do I need to worry?

Tags: python, malware, mingw64

I don't know why `w64.exe` files are getting generated in various location in my laptop. Quick Heal puts them in quarantine files. Are these files generated by Microsoft? How can I be sure regarding this? Or are these some sort of virus because I have been deleting such files since morning but they keep coming in different location.

[image]

Edit: After my conversation with @Gantendo [virus-total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) is [showing no virus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq9Kd.png) but Quick Heal Paid Application [shows it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao4Ua.jpg) as a virus file.

Comment: Upload one of the files to https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

Comment: Last time I turned PC restart then it came but now when I shut down my system and on it currently that file hasn't came. If it comes I will upload it to the website. Thanks @Gantendo

Comment: Shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq9Kd.png) after scanning @Gantendo

Comment: Though virustotal is showing no virus but Quick Heal is showing it as virus [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao4Ua.jpg) (I just got to know we can see virus of quarintine files)

Comment: I do not trust Quick Heal. I have never used it or even heard of it. Install malwarebytes from https://www.malwarebytes.com/ and let that scan the computer. Quick Heal detects it as a generic malware file so it may be a false positive. In which other locations did the `w64.exe` file show up? You have shortcuts to w64 on your desktop and it seems to be some kinda python thing.

Comment: “Are these files generated by Microsoft?” - Considering the file has absolutely no connection to Microsoft, Microsoft nor Windows, is generating that file. You can tell this isn’t a system file based on its location

Comment: @Gantendo free version of malwarebytes shows no threat

Comment: @JitendraSingh Good news, Quick Heal was wrong. There is no virus. You should probably uninstall Quick Heal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python's Documentation for [venv Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

> The venv module provides support for creating lightweight “virtual environments” with their own site directories, optionally isolated from system site directories

Now, further on the same site:

> usage: `venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear][--upgrade] [--without-pip] [--prompt PROMPT] [--upgrade-deps] ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]`

Here, I wouldn't say I know exactly what's happening, but I see a certain pattern — Python's lib folder have been copied back and again to `C:\users\jatin\venv` and to folders having the name of the arguements like `C:\users\jatin\[-h]` etc.  (As a matter of fact `\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib` does have a `w64.exe` and this is the only w64.exe in the python folder.)

Now, possibilities in order of decreasing probabilty are:

1. One of the OP's experiment with python created these wierd looking directories instead of creating a Virtualenv — Solution for this would be to simply delete those files created in `C:\users\jatin`
2. Python's programs got messed up — Solution for this would be to Reinstall python.
3. Some wierd malware is doing wierd things for wierd purposes: Scan your computer through. (As already said this is highly improbable.)

Although I would suggest you to start with a fresh installation of python and deleting those directories, just to make sure everything works like it should.

As for QuickHeal marking it as a malware, Many antiviruses sometimes mark python files as malwares. Also, the copied versions are still signed by microsoft. Long things short, there's no reason for you to worry.

Comment: For your last paragraph yes the files are signed by Microsoft but QuickHeal does shows them virus even with their name so do I need to worry?

Comment: Nope. To me, QuickHeal isn't reliable anymore. Rather use Malwarebytes or Bitdefender. And, they are signed by Microsoft, which actually means that they are the exact unedited copies of files present in python.